# Python list append adding element twice

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python and am trying out Django. I am seeing what is to me a strange behavior during a page request. I wrote my own class which extends the built-in `TemplateView` class so that I can override the `get_context_data` method of that class. In my new version of that method I am making changes to the `context` like so:

```
class adminUpload(TemplateView):
  template_name = "adminupload.tpl.html"

  def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(TemplateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['js_paths'] = webapp.settings.template['js_paths']

    logger.debug('adding')
    logger.debug( context['js_paths'] )

    context['js_paths'].append( '/static/path/to/js/file.js' )

    logger.debug( context['js_paths'] )

    return context
```

And in my url router I am passing requests to this class like so:

```
url(r'^adminupload$', front.adminUpload.as_view() ),
```

For some reason, each time I reload the page, my `context['js_paths']` list gets longer by one item, `'/static/path/to/js/file.js'` such that if I reload the page 5 times, the list will contain 5 items all appended to the end with that value. I can verify that the method is only being called once per request, and that the list does in fact seem to get bigger after each request by examining the debug log I setup.

I must be missing something very simple, some kind of caching, not understanding something about template context. Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `webapp.settings` referring to your app's settings? Consider using `from django.conf import settings` instead.

Comment: remove `context['js_paths'].append( '/static/path/to/js/file.js' )` or check `/static/path/to/js/file.js` on list before you append this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
context['js_paths'] = webapp.settings.template['js_paths']
context['js_paths'].append( '/static/path/to/js/file.js' )
```

Creates a new identifier to the same list and then appends to that list. You're not copying the list.

So everytime `get_context_data` is called `webapp.settings.template['js_paths']` is being appended to.

What you could do instead is:

```
context['js_paths'] = webapp.settings.template['js_paths'] + ['/static/path/to/js/file.js']
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, makes perfect sense that I would miss something that PHP glazes over for me. I will mark as answered in a few. I still don't understand why the list kept getting bigger. Aren't all these variables destroyed at the end of the request?

Comment: I suspect that `webapp.settings` stays instantiated for the life time of the django process for whatever way you're running it.

Comment: Thanks again, I think you may be on to something. I am using Nginx and uWSGI with a file socket connection. I think I need to read-up a little more about how these processes actually work.

Comment: `WSGI` uses long running python processes to handle web requests. If you list running processes on your server this should become clear.